# Why I am getting one clock cycle delay in Verilog case statement?

Tags: verilog, clock, delay, state-machines, sequential-logic

I have a Verilog code here:

```
module VendingMachine(
    input clk,
    input reset,
    input [1:0] coins ,
    output reg serving,
    output reg [1:0] state
    );
 parameter [1:0] WAIT  = 3'b10;
 parameter [1:0] READY  = 3'b01;
 parameter [1:0] SERVE  = 3'b11;
 
 always @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
 begin
  if (reset) 
  begin 
     state <= READY;
     serving   <= 0;
  end 
  else
    begin
        case(state)
        READY:    begin
               if (coins == 10) 
                    state <= SERVE;
               else if (coins == 01)
                    state <= WAIT;
               end
        WAIT:   begin 
                 if (coins == 01 || coins == 10) 
                        state <= SERVE;
                 else  
                        state <= WAIT;
                 end
        SERVE:   begin 
                 serving <= 1;
                 state <= READY;
                 end
        default: state <= WAIT;
        endcase
    end 
end 
endmodule
```

The output of the run is as follows:

```
0 clock=0 coins=xx state=01 serving=0
50 clock=1 coins=xx state=01 serving=0
100 clock=0 coins=xx state=01 serving=0
150 clock=1 coins=xx state=01 serving=0
200 clock=0 coins=01 state=01 serving=0
250 clock=1 coins=01 state=10 serving=0
300 clock=0 coins=01 state=10 serving=0
350 clock=1 coins=01 state=11 serving=0
400 clock=0 coins=01 state=11 serving=0
450 clock=1 coins=01 state=01 serving=1
500 clock=0 coins=01 state=01 serving=1
```

I was expecting to get the value of **serving** to change from zero to one when the value of **state** changed from 10 to 11, but there seems to be one complete clock cycle delay before the value of `serving` changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the positive edge of `clk` you change from `WAIT` state to `SERVE` state. You don't change the serving signal.

On the next clock cycle whilst in `SERVE` state, you change the `serving` signal to 1.

Notice how these two things happen in different clock periods? Essentially the value of the state machine itself always changes one clock before anything in the corresponding `case` statement happens.

---

As an aside you've written `coins == 10` (decimal 10), instead of `coins == 2'b10` (two bit binary number 10, decimal 2).  This works by sheer chance, as decimal 10 truncated to two bits equals 2.

Answer (score 4):

The [other answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/690102/72936) directly answers your question about the relative timing of your output signals, and it also provides an astute observation of a probable bug in your code (`10` vs. `2'b10`).

I also see another probable bug in the code.  The `serving` signal can only go back to 0 when you asynchronously reset the state machine.  I think you want to set `serving` to 0 in these states as well: `READY` and `WAIT`.  Otherwise, it remains high regardless of how you change the `coins` input.